# Valgrind- uninitialized values message

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've been getting some mysterious uninitialized values message from valgrind and it's been quite the mystery as of where the bad value originated from. Don't anyone know where is problem? Thanks a lot
There is memmory error, which i have been getting:

```
==26075== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==26075== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==26075== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==26075== Command: ./main
==26075== 
==26075== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==26075==    at 0x4C2A020: strcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:711)
==26075==    by 0x400CF6: stringcmp (main.c:121)
==26075==    by 0x4E64C69: msort_with_tmp (msort.c:84)
==26075==    by 0x4E6503B: qsort_r (msort.c:298)
==26075==    by 0x400930: main (main.c:42)
==26075== 
==26075== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==26075==    at 0x4C2A024: strcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:711)
==26075==    by 0x400CF6: stringcmp (main.c:121)
==26075==    by 0x4E64C69: msort_with_tmp (msort.c:84)
==26075==    by 0x4E6503B: qsort_r (msort.c:298)
==26075==    by 0x400930: main (main.c:42)
==26075== 
==26075== 
==26075== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26075==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26075==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 31 bytes allocated
==26075== 
==26075== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==26075== 
==26075== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==26075== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==26075== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

There is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *input;
int row = 0;


int stringcmp(const void *a, const void *b);

void permute(int n, int fix, char **arr);

int factorial(int n);

void swapSort(char array[], int left, int right);

void quick_sort(char *array, int left, int right);

void free2DArray(char **array, int row);

int main() {
    input = (char *) malloc(8 + 1 * sizeof(char));
    fgets(input, 9, stdin);
    int n = strlen(input);
    if (input[n - 1] == '\n') {
        n--;
        input[n] = '\0';
    }
    int f = factorial(n);
    printf("Length of string: %d\n", n);
    printf("Input string: \"%s\"\n", input);
    quick_sort(input, 0, n);
    printf("Sorted: \"%s\"\n", input);
    printf("Number of permutations: %d\n", f);
    char **arrOfPermutations = (char **) malloc(factorial(n) * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < factorial(n); i++) {
        arrOfPermutations[i] = (char *) malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char));
    }

    permute(n, n, arrOfPermutations);
    qsort(arrOfPermutations, f, sizeof(char *), stringcmp);
    for (int i = 0; i < f; i++) {
        printf("\"");
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%c", arrOfPermutations[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\"\n");
    }
    free2DArray(arrOfPermutations, f);
    free(input);

    return 0;
}


void free2DArray(char **array, int row) {
    for (row -= 1; row >= 0; row--)
        free(array[row]);
    free(array);
}

void permute(int n, int fix, char **arr) {
    int i, j;
    char temp;
    if (n == 0) {
        for (j = fix - 1, i = 0; j >= 0; j--, i++) {
            arr[row][i] = input[j];
        }
        row++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp = input[i];
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            input[j - 1] = input[j];
        }
        input[n - 1] = temp;

        permute(n - 1, fix, arr);

        for (j = n - 1; j > i; j--) {
            input[j] = input[j - 1];
        }
        input[i] = temp;
    }
}

int factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    return n * factorial(n - 1);

}


void quick_sort(char *array, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int boundary = left;
        for (int i = left + 1; i < right; i++) {
            if (array[i] < array[left]) {
                swapSort(array, i, ++boundary);
            }
        }
        swapSort(array, left, boundary);
        quick_sort(array, left, boundary);
        quick_sort(array, boundary + 1, right);
    }

}

void swapSort(char array[], int left, int right) {
    char tmp = array[right];
    array[right] = array[left];

    array[left] = tmp;
}


int stringcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const char **ia = (const char **) a;
    const char **ib = (const char **) b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}
```

Comment: By the way - `8 + 1 * sizeof(char)` works not like you expected

Comment: @fukanchik Using `sizeof(char)` in a multiplication is like using *sin(x)sin(x) + cos(x)cos(x)*.

Comment: Sorry, valgrind didn't report a single problem with this program as it is. Please explain what is the input?

Comment: input where is problem is "aa"

Comment: Your valgrind report appears to be complaining about the sorting performed by `qsort(arrOfPermutations, f, sizeof(char *), stringcmp);`.  It believes that among the strings being sorted, there is at least one that has been allocated, but has not had data written to it at some of the positions being read.  Your code is sufficiently convoluted that I cannot easily verify valgrind's claim, but I have no reason to doubt it.

Comment: Calling `factorial(n)` every time through the `for` loop makes me want to cry.

Comment: Especially since you earlier did `f = factorial(n)`, so you could just use `f` there.

Comment: I think the basic problem is that `arrOfPermutations` has `factorial(n)` elements, but you only initialize the first `n` elements in `permute()`. Then you try to sort the whole thing, so valgrind correctly complains about all the uninitialized elements.

Comment: @Barmar  i use variable `f` now, i just add there not the latest version of my code, i know that it is  horrible :D

Comment: @Barmar but in `permute` i add  factorial(n)*string about length `n` to an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from few other smaller problems You are correctly reverse-copying a string however without appending zero-byte at the end.

```
if (n == 0) {
    for (j = fix - 1, i = 0; j >= 0; j--, i++) { <<-- The problem is in this line
        arr[row][i] = input[j];
    }
    row++;
}
```

You can't reverse- copy end-of-line marker as it should remain in the end, so you have to add it afterwards:

```
if (n == 0) {
    for (j = fix - 1, i = 0; j >= 0; j--, i++) { 
        arr[row][i] = input[j];
    }
    arr[row][fix]=0; <<-- the fix
    row++;
}
```